# Managing RHEL updates - Do I have to use RHN?

Tags: centos, redhat, rpm, rhel

We use RackSpace for our private cloud and we get to spin up RHEL instances all day everyday, which brings me round to the issue of managing the updates on these systems.

I told everyone to use CentOS, until we can get around to managing the licensing, so I can manage the repos, and take control over what packages are available, security updates and the like.

Do I have to use RHN to manage RHEL packages, or can I use an in house system for systems to collect packages from?

/* please excuse the naiveness of this question - personally, I can't see any reason why I can't use "createrepo" but I though I'd just ask the community to make sure */

Answer (score 0):

CentOS patches are usually within 2-3 days of RHEL, so you should be fine. (Security patches - releases are a whole other story!) Depending on your company size, etc, you may want to pick up a few RHEL licenses anyway to help contribute...